# How to sum the current column value in row with the previous value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+-----------+
| xType   | xAccID | xAccName | xCat | xYear | xMonth | xRaseed   |
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+-----------+
| Amounts | 52     | Acc1     | Rs   | 2020  | 11     | 3144.83   |
| Amounts | 52     | Acc1     | Rs   | 2020  | 12     | -15199.64 |
| Amounts | 53     | Acc2     | Cus  | 2020  | 12     | 5306.04   |
| Amounts | 53     | Acc2     | Cus  | 2020  | 11     | 1090.64   |
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+-----------+
```

actually, I want to sum the (xRaseed) in the current row with the (xRaseed) in the previous row **For each (xAccID) separately**

the result that I want:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+
| xType   | xAccID | xAccName | xCat | xYear | xMonth | xRaseed                        |
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+
| Amounts | 52     | Acc1     | Rs   | 2020  | 11     | 3144.83                        | 
| Amounts | 52     | Acc1     | Rs   | 2020  | 12     | Not -15199.64 But (-12,054.81) |
| Amounts | 53     | Acc2     | Cus  | 2020  | 12     | 5306.04                        |
| Amounts | 53     | Acc2     | Cus  | 2020  | 11     | Not 1090.64 But (6,396.68)     |
+---------+--------+----------+------+-------+--------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: .. I'm confused.  How is the ordering of the rows determined.  The last two rows look like they are in the wrong order.

Comment: no they are right

Comment: @Hamada: Please comment on the statement "How is the ordering of the rows determined"

Comment: ORDER BY xAccID,xYear,xMonth

Comment: Plainly, that's not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "previous" row unless columns specify the ordering.  In your data, that would suggest `xYear` and `xMonth` -- even thought the results do not follow this rule.

Assuming you want a chronological ordering (or ordering based on any columns), then you can use a cumulative sum window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(xRaseed) over (partition by xAccID order by xYear, xMonth) as running_xRaseed
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c425e64d5ad6f6a4c252fa4bb1e5816a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thank you, it's working, I would like to ask how to pass(maybe delete) the first row for each (xAccID) with sum its value (xRaseed) with the value (xRaseed) in the second row before passing it?

Comment: @Hamada . . . Can you ask a new question with clear sample data, results, and explanation?

Comment: everything was working in the local server but when I applied the solution on my hosting, didn't work?? in the local I use (xampp - 10.4.17-MariaDB), and in my hosting I use (MySQL 5.7.23-23), what's the problem please?

Comment: @Hamada . . . This uses window functions which require MysQL 8+.  I would suggest that you actually us the same database on both systems.  Barring that, you should upgrade to a more recent version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It goes a little something like this, in MySQL 8+:

```
SUM(xRaseed) OVER(PARTITION BY xAccId ORDER BY xYear DESC, xMonth DESC)
```

Though I should point out that your "previous row" concept is broken. In one of your sets the dates increase, in the other, they decrease. If it's supposed to be that way i.e. "for `xCat = 'Rs` the dates increase, but for `Cus` they decrease`" then some fiddle like:

```
SUM(xRaseed) OVER(
  PARTITION BY xAccId 
  ORDER BY 
    xYear * CASE WHEN xCat = 'Rs' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END, 
    xMonth * CASE WHEN xCat = 'Rs' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END
)
```